# How to join ef navigation properties in linq to entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I try to get the following sql written in Linq to Entities:

```
SELECT * FROM SafetySheets AS SS
JOIN UserProfiles AS UP ON SS.CreatedBy = UP.UserId
JOIN SafetyOfficers AS SO ON SS.SafetyOfficer_Id = SO.Id
JOIN Projects AS Pr ON SS.Project_Id = Pr.Id
JOIN ConstructionLocations AS CL ON SS.ConstructionLocation_Id = CL.Id
JOIN ProductionManagers AS PM ON SS.ProductionManager_Id = PM.Id
JOIN ConstructionManagers AS CM ON SS.ConstructionManager_Id = CM.Id
```

Here is my attempt in Linq:

```
public IQueryable<SafetySheetCollection> GetSafetySheets()
    {
        var query = from vSafety in _db.SafetySheets
                    join vUserProfile in _db.UserProfiles
                    on vSafety.CreatedBy equals vUserProfile.UserId
                    join vProject in _db.Projects
                    on vSafety.Id equals vProject.SafetySheets
                    join vConstructionLocation in _db.ConstructionLocations
                    on vSafety.Id equals vConstructionLocation.SafetySheets
                    join vSafetyOfficer in _db.SafetyOfficers
                    on vSafety.Id equals vSafetyOfficer.SafetySheets
                    join vProductionManager in _db.ProductionManagers
                    on vSafety.Id equals vProductionManager.SafetySheets
                    join vConstructionManager in _db.ConstructionManagers
                    on vSafety.Id equals vConstructionManager.SafetySheets
                    orderby vSafety.Created descending
                    select new SafetySheetCollection
                    {
                        ListAllSafetySheets = vSafety,
                        ListAllUserProfiles = vUserProfile,
                        ListAllProjects = vProject,
                        ListAllConstructionLocations = vConstructionLocation,
                        ListAllSafetyOfficers = vSafetyOfficer,
                        ListAllProductionManagers = vProductionManager,
                        ListAllConstructionManagers = vConstructionManager
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

The SheetCollection model:

```
 public class SafetySheetCollection
 {
    public SafetySheet ListAllSafetySheets { get; set; }
    public Project ListAllProjects { get; set; }
    public ConstructionLocation ListAllConstructionLocations { get; set; }
    public UserProfile ListAllUserProfiles { get; set; }
    public SafetyOfficer ListAllSafetyOfficers { get; set; }
    public ProductionManager ListAllProductionManagers { get; set; }
    public ConstructionManager ListAllConstructionManagers { get; set; }
 }
```

My diagram looks like this:

[image]

I understand that it doesn't work out to equal with a navigation property. But how should this be done in a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on [joins in linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) is not that hard to find. The `equals` should be on scalar properties, commonly the ones that correspond with the FK constraint in the database.

```
from vSafety in _db.SafetySheets
join vUserProfile in _db.UserProfiles
    on vSafety.CreatedById equals vUserProfile.UserId // CreatedById !
...
```

I could have just mentioned this in a comment if there would not be another, much more consise way of joining I'd like to pint out as well (documented, but somehow often overlooked):

```
from vUserProfile in _db.UserProfiles
from vSafety in vUserProfile.SafetySheets // not db.SafetySheets
...
```

Your queries are a bit too big for me to sort out all the joins but this should help you to get it done.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've earlier done the joins on linq to sql and it worked out just fine as you describe above. But it doesn't work out when I try with linq to entities. I dont get a hold of the foreign key which are a navigation property with ICollection. The SafetySheet table holds all the foreign keys and get simple join with SQL is just a piece of cake. But it's a bit troublesome in Linq to Entities.

Comment: And the SafetySheet table has a many to one relation to all the other tables.